# Calabash-Android dragging button with Drag Shadow

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, drag, robotium, calabash

I'm using a simple app with an on drag listener to drag a button from one half of the screen to the other. I am able to drag the element fine, on any emulator or device, and using the drag function implemented by Monkey Runner. When I try to use calabash to drag the element across the screen using "performAction('drag',50,30,25,75,15)" (and drag_coordinates), the Drag Shadow appears and then the dragging motion is immediately stopped (see picture).

[image: drag]

Any other drag (not on a draggable element) works, including those that open drawers or those that "move" rectangles drawn on the canvas. I've tried to make the Drag Shadow empty, in case it is interfering with the dragging. The broken drag animation then prevents any other interactions with calabash, unless I interact with the device to cancel the drag.

Has anyone else noticed a similar issue with dragging an element/object across the screen and having it freeze when the drag begins? I realize that Calabash uses robotium at its core so if either of those test frameworks would apply to this. I am using the most recent calabash-android-0.4.21 and even just tried the beta 0.5 version.

MainActivity code:
    `package com.example.dragndrop;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.view.DragEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button drag;
LinearLayout drop;
TextView text,sucess;
int total , failure = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    drag = (Button)findViewById(R.id.one);
    drop = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.toplinear);
    text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Total);
    sucess = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Sucess);
    sucess.setText("Sucessful Drops :"+(total - failure));
    text.setText("Total Drops: "+total);
    drag.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  final int action = event.getAction();
        switch(action) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
  break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
          break;
  case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
    break;
  case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:{
            failure = failure+1;
    return(true);
  }
  case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:{
    total = total +1;
    int suc = total - failure;
    sucess.setText("Sucessful Drops :"+suc);
            text.setText("Total Drops: "+total);
    return(true);
  }
  default:
        break;
        }
  return true;
  }});
        drag.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
    View.DragShadowBuilder shadow = new View.DragShadowBuilder(drag);
    v.startDrag(data, shadow, null, 0);
    return false;
  }
});
}
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution:

`performAction('drag',50,30,25,75,1)`

---

or this one:

`%x{#{default_device.adb_command} shell input swipe 50 30 25 75 15}`